# WindowShade and CollapsibleAccordion problems, migrating from Flex3 to Flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have two problems in my code:

First: is with the WindowShade. I have a WindowShade in my application, and the moment I click to run this everything just hangs up. This was working fine when I was using the Flex3 to compile.

The code looks like:

```
<mdi_containers:MDIWindow xmlns:mdi_containers="flexlib.mdi.containers.*"
xmlns:flexlib_controls="flexlib.controls.*"                
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"      
xmlns:containers="flexlib.containers.*"
          width="800" layout="absolute"
          height="500" title="News Articles"       
          textAlign="center"
          verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0"
      minWidth="800"
          minHeight="500">
    <mx:Canvas  width="100%" styleName="roundedBottomCorner">

    <containers:WindowShade id="wshade_fox" top="0" width="100%" opened="false" visible="true"
            openIcon="{null}" closeIcon="{null}" paddingTop="0" 
            headerRenderer="{new ClassFactory(c7.views.components.news.header)}">                                              
<mx:VBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" width="100%" height="225" verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0">
</mx:VBox>                                     
                        </containers:WindowShade>                                           
</mx:Canvas>
```

Second: The CollapsibleAccordion. I have two canvas inside the CollapsibleAccordion, and everything works fine in Flex4 also, but the only problem, that i am unable to see the label on the Canvas.

The code for this problem is below:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"                
            xmlns:cal="cal.*"
            layout="absolute"
            addedToStage="stage_init()"
applicationComplete="init()"                            
        xmlns:geometry="com.degrafa.geometry.*"
        xmlns:degrafa="com.degrafa.*"
        xmlns:paint="com.degrafa.paint.*"
        xmlns:containers="flexlib.containers.*"
        xmlns:flexlib_controls="flexlib.controls.*"
        xmlns:mdi_containers="flexlib.mdi.containers.*"
        xmlns:auto="com.hillelcoren.components.*" 
        xmlns:local="*" backgroundColor="#f7fafe" backgroundGradientColors="[#f7fafe, #6caaeb]"
        xmlns:components="CollapsibleAccordion.*"
        xmlns:notifications="c7.views.components.notifications.*"
        xmlns:dbview="c7.views.apps.dashboard.*"
        modalTransparency="0.8" preloader="c7.views.components.Pre"
        modalTransparencyColor="0x000000" verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
        backgroundSize="100%"               
        xmlns:components1="c7.views.components.*" 
        xmlns:notification="c7.views.components.notification.*" 
        xmlns:news="c7.views.components.news.*">    
    <mdi_containers:MDICanvas id="mdic" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
        visible="{!GlobalModel.getInstance().dashboard_mode}"
         minWidth="{top_bar.width}"
        width="100%" height="100%" top="{top_bar.height}" backgroundAlpha="0">                              
       <mx:Canvas id="cvs_widget_bar" right="0" top="0" height="100%">
            <components:CollapsibleAccordion id="collapsibleAccordion1" height="100%" top="0" right="0"
                orientation="left" barSize="30" currentWidth="30" openSize="150"
                drawerButtonStyle="drawerButton" closeButtonStyle="drawerCloseRight" accordianStyle="drawerAccordion">
                <mx:Canvas width="100%" top="0" right="0" height="100%" label="Widget Bar">

                </mx:Canvas>
                <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="Feedback" icon="{IconUtility.getClass(cvs_comment,'assets/cloud_main/images/article-48x48.png')}"
                    id="cvs_comment" top="0" right="0">

                </mx:Canvas>
            </components:CollapsibleAccordion>
        </mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had simliar problems with WindowShade going from Flex 3 to Flex 4. I had to define a button for the headerClass. Since I had a bunch of WindowShades, I added in my style sheet:

```
flexlib|WindowShade {
   headerClass:ClassReference("mx.controls.Button");
}
```

Or, if you want when you declare a WindowShade, you can add in your MXML:

```
headerClass="mx.controls.Buttons"
```

...so that way your "wshade_fox" declaration looks something like:

```
<containers:WindowShade id="wshade_fox" top="0" width="100%" opened="false" visible="true"
        openIcon="{null}" closeIcon="{null}" paddingTop="0" 
        headerRenderer="{new ClassFactory(c7.views.components.news.header)}"
        headerClass="mx.controls.Button">
```

Hope that helps the first part of your problem.